# Source code for the AC_PROG_CC macro

Tags: autoconf

I've tried checking the Autoconf git repo contents, but I've found nothing that looks like that macro. What would be a possible way to get hold of the m4 source code of this macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, `which autoconf` will yield a directory of the form `BASE/bin/autoconf`, in which case (as of autoconf 2.69), you will probably find the `autoconf` macros in `BASE/share/autoconf`.

Look at `BASE/share/autoconf/autoconf/c.m4`

Or from the repo, [`c.m4`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf.git;a=blob;f=lib/autoconf/c.m4;hb=HEAD), though this differs from the current 2.69 release, in that it sets flags for C11 / C99 / C90. It's not clear what the plan is for a '2.70' release, which has been a *long* time coming.